# linux mint mysql-server and mysql-workbench installation and setup issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, linux-mint, mysqladmin

I tried to below OS installed on my laptop

```
Mint version 19, 
Code name : Tara,
PackageBase : Ubuntu Bionic
Cinnamon (64-bit)
```

I have installed mysql-server using below command:

```
xxxxxxx:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

During this installation I was not prompted to enter any root password.
TO see if installation was successful, I ran below command:

```
xxxxxxxxxx:~$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
xxxxxxxxxx:~$ sudo service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-09-30 21:59:42 EDT; 9s ago
 Main PID: 3518 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 27 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─3518 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Sep 30 21:59:41 globallogic systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Sep 30 21:59:42 globallogic systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

As I was not prompted to set any root password, I thought of setting root password.

```
xxxxxxxx:~$ mysqladmin -u root password
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''
xxxxxxxx:~$ sudo mysqladmin -u root password
New password: 
Confirm new password: 
Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
```

*1. Why I can't be able to use "mysqladmin" command without being logged in as root?*

*2. How to fix the warning for mysqladmin set root password? ANd can I be able to use that password inside mysql workbench in future if decide to use it?*

---

After setting root password(assuming that's the right way to set it) , I have installed mysql-workbench

```
xxxxxxx:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

When I launch mysql workbench, I can't be able to connect to 
user:root using hostname: localhost and port: 3306 and password set using mysqladmin command.

I also tried to use hostname: 127.0.0.1 but that didn't work either.

*3. How to fix mysql-workbench issue?*

I looked on internet to find answers for this and tried multiple solutions, but none worked.

Hoping to get cleaner answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Installed **mysql workbench version 6.3** and **mysql server version 5.7**

Before installing I cleaned any mysql files/references I had on my linux machine.

> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*  
> sudo apt-get purge mysql*  
> sudo apt-get autoremove  
> sudo apt-get autoclean  
> sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
> ```

**Below steps worked fine for me** -

1. Go to the download page for the MySQL APT repository at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ and downloaded *mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb*
2. Made sure everything is up to date.

> ```
> xxxxxxxxx:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get update
> ```

3. installed downloaded deb file.

> ```
> xxxxxxxxx:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb 
> Selecting previously unselected package mysql-apt-config.
> (Reading database ... 273762 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb ...
> Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
> Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
> Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
> OK
> ```

during this step chose mysql server version 5.7

4. After this ran *sudo apt-get update* and then ran

> ```
> xxxxxxxxx:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
> ```

during this step, I was prompted to to set root password. Ended up setting root password as 'pa$$word'

If you are not prompted to set root password then you can follow following commands once above command is completed.
sudo mysql

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pa$$word';
exit;
```

5. After installation is successful checked status

> ```
> xxxxxxxxx:~/Downloads$ sudo service mysql status
> ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
>    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>    Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-10-01 15:31:19 EDT; 29s ago
>  Main PID: 23029 (mysqld)
>     Tasks: 27 (limit: 4915)
>    CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
>            └─23029 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
>
> Oct 01 15:31:18  systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
> Oct 01 15:31:19  systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
> ```

6. Then tried to check if I can go to mysql prompt.

> ```
> xxxxxxxx:~/Downloads$ mysql -u root -p
> Enter password: 
> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
> Your MySQL connection id is 2
> Server version: 5.7.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
> affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
> owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
>
> mysql> show databases;
> +--------------------+
> | Database           |
> +--------------------+
> | information_schema |
> | mysql              |
> | performance_schema |
> | sys                |
> +--------------------+
> 4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> quit
> Bye
> ```

7. Then installed mysql workbench using below command

> xxxxxxxxxxx:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

8. Launched mysql workbench from start menu on linux mint 19.
   Here Server connection has parameteres like *hostname: 127.0.0.1 , port:3306, Username: root, password: pa$$word*. The tested connection - successful.
9. double clicked connection and it launched instance fine.